# Loop and release sections on Wavs

Tags: looping, wav, wave-editor

Hi All

I was wondering what, or if, there is a programme on osx I can use (free would be a plus) that will let me export audio files with looping sections.

I.e. A wav that will end at one point if it is repeatedly triggered and will end at another point when it is left to play out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks so much

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many audio editing software that allow loop markers to be saved. This information is saved in the .wav info chink, and will be readable by various other pieces of software or hardware samplers. On OSX, Bias Peak is one I know has this function. I'm not aware of any free audio editors that have the capacity to export loop markers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am creating some SFX for a game and I think some of the sounds would benefit form this function. I have also seen now that sound forge has this function, I wonder if I should just bootcamp.

Comment: @Missing-Link - Sound forge is the defacto standard for adding markers to files and does it easily and well. It is also used a lot in game sound creation because of this and a few other features that are easier in SF than other programmes. Damn shame it is only for Windows ... I would recommend the boot camp option ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wave Editor and Loop Editor by Audiofile Engineering is the best audio editor and loop tool for the Mac that I'm aware of:  http://www.audiofile-engineering.com/waveeditor

I would go so far as to call it the SoundForge of Mac OS.  It's also very reasonably priced (Loop Editor $49.99, and Wave Editor on sale currently at $69.99), and you can download a 15-day full featured demo I believe.  I also couldn't live without their Sample Manager software.  All of them handle audio file markers -- Wave Editor can add loops points too, but Loop Editor gives some extra functionality that comes in handy, like a zero-cross view.

Answer (score 1):

check out twistedwave for mac

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the new major player on the mac - adobe audition, once known as cooledit/coolpro.

Support and implementation for these markers and how they are interpreted varies from software to software and if you're working with an SDK that too would be specific about the kind of markers it expects to see. I think that's as much standardised as these things get........ :/ Definitely check out the trial versions before you commit to a specific product.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
First post !

I think Adobe Audition appears to become the new standard for editing on Mac Os. I'm using it and it's really cool.
You can try it during 30 days :
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=audition

Enjoy.